# Add data in listview from another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I'm doing an application which selects a random string from the strings.xml file, and I want to make a history of the elements that gives you, so I'm using a ListView.

So, how can I add this text to the list?

Thank you very much!

(Sorry for my bad English)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Edited  ++++++++++++++++++++++++

Sorry, here is the "escoger.xml" file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEscoger"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Aleatorio"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/btnEscoger"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTituloComida"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the "escoger.java" file, the controller of "escoger.xml"

```
    package org.example.app;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Escoger extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tvTituloComida;
Button btnEscoger;

int plato;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.escoger);

    tvTituloComida = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTituloComida);
    btnEscoger = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEscoger);

    btnEscoger.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.btnEscoger:

        Random r=new Random();
        plato = r.nextInt(4-1);

        if(plato==1){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida1); }
        if(plato==2){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida2); }
        if(plato==3){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida3); }
        if(plato==4){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida4); }

        break;
    }
    }
    }
```

The "historia.xml":

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHistorialTilte"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Tilte_History"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the "Historia.java", is what I don't know how to do...

```
package org.example.app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Historia extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.historia);

           //Code here

}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Start by adding some code and let us know the exact problem you are having

Comment: Sorry, @codeMagic. Now I've put the the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The most straightforward is to [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) your data and pass it [directly through the `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29). Alternatively, you could store them in an [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

The flow will look something like this:

- `Activity A` records and stores the selected strings locally or in SQLite DB
- Optional: Pass `Bundle` containing history to `History Activity`
- Load data in `History Activity`'s `onCreate`. If you pass it through the `Intent`, use `getIntent().getExtras()`. If you use SQLite, you'll likely end up using a simple [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

If you want the history to be stored *persistently*, you'll need to use an SQLite DB regardless of your methods here. In that case, I'd recommend just going with the DB for loading the History as well. If you *don't* want persistant storage, I'd go with the `Intent` and `Bundle`.

At this point, you'd simply throw your `List<String>` into an adapter and call your `ListView`'s `setAdapter()` function.